# "Não dizer nada" é um verbo?

Tags: verbos, sintaxe, classe-gramatical

Tenho dúvidas sobre a formação de verbos com mais de uma palavra.

Por exemplo:

- não dizer nada;
- gostar de dançar;
- criar um filho;

Os exemplos acima são verbos ou podemos classificá-los como tendo outra função gramatical?

Comment: Cada frase tem UM VERBO: dizer, gostar, criar. Não existe formação de verbo com mais de uma palavra. O que você colocou são frases inteiras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta pergunta, na verdade, é sobre funções sintáticas, e não sobre classes gramaticais.

Na língua portuguesa, verbos são constituídos de uma única palavra (às vezes, seguida de um pronome, como em *rir-se* ou *tratar-se*). Quando uma ação usa mais de um verbo, chamamos de locução verbal, composta de um verbo auxiliar (geralmente ser/estar/ter/haver/ir) e um ou mais verbos no infinitivo, particípio ou gerúndio:

> Ainda *estou pensando* se sairei esta noite.
>
> As crianças *têm sido deixadas* de lado pelos pais.

Os exemplos que você citou não são locuções verbais, porém. São **predicados**: verbos propriamente ditos, acompanhados de conjuntos de palavras de outras classes gramaticais (substantivos, artigos, advérbios, outros verbos) que desempenham funções sintáticas complementares ou subordinadas aos verbos. Tomando a liberdade de fugir um pouco da função gramatical:

> **não dizer nada**
>
> "não" é da classe gramatical *advérbio* e desempenha a função sintática *complemento adverbial*;
>
> "dizer" é da classe gramatical *verbo* e desempenha a função sintática *núcleo do predicado*;
>
> "nada" é da classe gramatical *pronome* e desempenha a função sintática *objeto direto*.

---

> **gostar de dançar**
>
> "gostar" é da classe gramatical *verbo* e desempenha a função sintática *núcleo do predicado*;
>
> "de" é da classe gramatical *preposição* e desempenha a função sintática *adjunto adnominal* (apesar de "dançar" ser um verbo!);
>
> "dançar" é da classe gramatical *verbo* e desempenha a função sintática *objeto indireto*. Aqui é que fica complicado: como "dançar" é um novo verbo independente do anterior, ele define uma nova oração, composta somente por ele mesmo. Nesta nova oração, ele é o *núcleo do predicado*. Como esta nova oração serve de objeto indireto ao verbo "gostar", uma função geralmente reservada aos substantivos, dizemos que ela é *subordinada substantiva objetiva indireta*.

---

> **criar um filho**
>
> "criar" é da classe gramatical *verbo* e desempenha a função sintática *núcleo do predicado*;
>
> "um" é da classe gramatical *artigo* e desempenha a função sintática *adjunto adnominal*;
>
> "filho" é da classe gramatical *substantivo* e desempenha a função sintática *núcleo do objeto direto*.

---

Então, respondendo à pergunta: não, eles não são verbos, eles são *predicados*, ou seja, são verbos acompanhados de palavras que lhes completam o sentido.

Comment: Neste caso *não* e *nada* não formam um conjunto sintático qualquer? Afinal *não disse nada* não é a negação de *disse nada*.

Comment: Coisas como *rir-se, arrepender-se* serão exceções à regra de o verbo ser formado por uma palavra  só? O clítico não tem nenhum significado próprio nestes exemlos.

Comment: @Jacinto Eu concordo sobre o "não dizer nada", mas achei que ficaria confuso demais para entender. Do jeito que ficou, já penso que a transição do assunto "classe gramatical" para "função sintática" não ficou das mais suaves. Como você sugeriria refrasear este trecho?

Comment: @Jacinto Considero que estes verbos seriam uma palavra só (composta), mas acho válida a clarificação. Vou editar.

Comment: @Jacinto Refletindo melhor aqui, não se consideraria o _-se_ como um pronome oblíquo? Afinal, na flexão dos verbos e na colocação pronominal, ele se comporta como um: _não me arrependo de ter-me rido durante a cerimônia_.

Comment: Sim, sim, são pronomes oblíquos. *Rir-se: rio-me, ris-te, não me rio, não te ris*, etc. Mas estes clíticos são o quê? Não têm significado próprio. Eu não sei muito destas coisas. Isto são tudo perguntas genuínas. Também não sei como classificar o *não ... nada*. Locução adverbial?

Comment: @Jacinto Também não sei. O verbo demanda o uso deles, disto eu me recordo, mas qual função desempenham na oração? Necessito de pesquisa.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52821/discussion-between-jacinto-and-ramon-melo).

Comment: Para pregunta simples, melhor resposta simples.

Comment: Eu votei negativo porque considero que a resposta tem informacão incorreta.

Comment: @BrunoCosta Respeito sua decisão, mas seria interessante esclarecer qual parte da informação está incorreta. Nem eu, nem o autor disse que as orações estão bem formadas. De fato, o sujeito da oração é irrelevante para a pergunta (e talvez assunto para uma nova pergunta).

Comment: @`Os exemplos que você citou não são locuções verbais, porém. São predicados.` Eles não sao predicados bem formados.

Comment: @BrunoCosta Como não? Todos os três são predicados válidos: "você veio à reunião para _não dizer nada_?"; "foi na escola de samba que aprendi a _gostar de dançar_"; "as imposições deste governo tornam muito mais difícil _criar um filho_ neste país". Faltam-lhes o sujeito para dar coerência, com certeza, mas a função sintática deles enquanto predicados está bem definida.

Comment: @RamonMelo Nessa sua oracao o predicao é "veio á reuniao". "Para nao dizer nada" é uma proposicao. Já na segunda o predicado é "que  aprendi" Na terceira é "tornam muito mais dificil"

Comment: @BrunoCosta Orações subordinadas também possuem predicados, afinal, continuam sendo orações.

Comment: @RamonMelo Certo, mas os exemplos dados pelo perguntador nao sao corretos como orações primárias.

Comment: E nem precisam estar corretos, ele está perguntando só sobre os verbos. Eu estendi o assunto para análise sintática somente com a intenção de explicar por que "não dizer nada" não é um verbo, embora expresse uma (in)ação. Avaliar se os predicados são válidos ou não em orações primárias já seria assunto para uma nova pergunta.

Comment: @BrunoCosta Reconheço que minha resposta tangenciou o tema da pergunta. Particularmente, eu deveria ter feito mais esforço em sintetizar minhas ideias e evitar as repetições. Tendo dito isto, o escopo da pergunta continua sendo só os verbos. A análise sintática foi uma transgressão minha, um recurso para tornar minha explicação menos nebulosa.

Answer (score 0):

Uma coisa não dita na resposta do @Ramon é que nenhuma das frases nos exemplos dados constitui uma oração bem formada.

Para uma oração ser bem formada ela tem que ter um sujeito e um predicado.

Nenhuma das frases dos exemplos contém um sujeito, nem sequer um predicado, como o @Ramon sugeriu.

A razão é muito simples, [a wikipédia explica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicado_(gram%C3%A1tica)):

> Quando é um caso de oração sem sujeito, o verbo do predicado fica na
> forma impessoal, 3ª pessoa do singular. O núcleo do predicado pode ser
> um verbo significativo, um nome ou ambos.

Pondo esta regra em prática os exemplos dados pelo perguntador ficariam:

> não disse nada;
>
> gosta de dançar;
>
> cria um filho;

Agora sim cada uma das orações, tem um predicado válido. Também é possível entender estas orações com sujeito nulo subentendido e o sujeito pode até ser diferente, consoante o contexto, veja-se:

> (Eu, ele) não disse nada;
>
> (Ele) gosta de dançar;
>
> (Ele) cria um filho;

É possível construir orações com sujeito nulo subentendido para qualquer pronome pessoal:

> Vou ao cinema
>
> Vais ao cinema
>
> Vai ao cinema
>
> Vamos ao cinema
>
> Ides ao cinema
>
> Vão ao cinema